# how to fix memory leaks with xcode (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management

i've made a game in Swift and it has a single and a multiplayer modes, and it seems that i have a problem with the memory management, because the app occupies 150 MB and i have no idea why.
the memory debugger of xcode shows that there are 15 issues when i choose a multiplayer game, but in the single player mode it semmes that there are no leaks and still it got 150 MB usage.
here are a screenshot of the debugger in action and i'll appreciate any help with all these triangles, circles and rombs.
thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a **strong reference cycle**.
Usually this happens when you don't declare objects that you use in closures as `weak`. In order to understand what a **strong reference cycle** is, check the following resources out:

1. [Blog post about strong reference cycles](http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift)
2. WWDC videos available (e.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/242/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/410/))

Although the WWDC videos are a little bit older, the main idea is still the same. At least two objects are (transitively) holding a **strong** reference to each other. When both get released (e.g. when a `GameScene` is deallocated) they still point to one another, so the system is unable to deallocate them.

Usually, you get a strong reference cycles in the context of closures:

```
myMethod(...) { (param1, param2) in
   self.myVariable = ...
}
```

If you have a structure like this in your code, try to make **self** `weak`. i.e.

```
myMethod(...) { [unowned self] (param1, param2) in 
   self.myVariable = ...
}
```

Since I don't see the code, I can't exactly see where the problem is but it seems that you have a strong reference cycle in your dictionaries. Then it might not be a closure problem.

Comment: thanks, i'm reading about references now. despite the issues previously mentioned, i think the problem with the RAM usage is completely different story, because in single player mode there are no issues and still it uses too much RAM. is there any way to see which element how many RAM uses? i'm starting to think that the problem is in the images, not the size (they are 500 kb the biggest), but in the resolution. i'm looking for more information about this now. if you know some good resources you're welcome to share it! thanks!

Comment: Allocation list might be what you're looking for: https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started